# Yii2 Framework to Azure Web App (404 Page Not Found)

Tags: azure, yii2, azure-web-app-service

Thank for reading my post.

I'm having an issue making my Website Application(Yii2) works correctly in Azure Web Apps. I've migrated my Yii2 Websites from an existing server to the Azure Web Apps. After lots of manipulation listed below, I’m able to access the Website.

The main theme loads successfully but throwing "404 Page not found
The requested page is missing, or the address has been changed" Error in the body and others links in the "Menu Bar" not working too. "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

**The Azure Resources are configured as below:**

- 1 x App Service Plan : S1:1 (Windows Base)
- 1 x Azure Database for MySQL server
- 1 x App Service (The Web App)

**App Service Application Setting:**

- .Net Framwork: v4.7
- PHP Version: 7.0
- Platform: 32bit

**Migration Steps:**

1. FTP all files/folder from `htdocs` in my existing server to my App Service Plan (`\site/wwwroot`)
2. Generate the SQL Table creation in PhpAdmin
3. Find and Replace  `ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;` in the script
4. Connect to Azure Database for MySQL server, create new Schema and Run the Script
5. From Azure, KUDU Inferface browse (\site\wwwroot\config) and change the db.php to

   ```
   <?php

   return [
       'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
       'dsn' => 'mysql:host=xxxx.mysql.database.azure.com;dbname=xxxxx',
       'username' => 'xxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
       'password' => 'xxxxxx',
       'charset' => 'utf8',
   ];
   ```
6. Restart the Web App
7. Check the https://yourdomain.com/requirements.php (Passed without any Error)
8. "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable" when trying to browse the new Web App.
9. KUDO PowerShell windows browse back to `site/wwwroot` and executed the following line of codes

   ```
   php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
   php composer-setup.php
   php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"
   ```
10. Browse to the Directory (\site\wwwroot\web) and change index.php with the following line of codes:

    ```
    if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'on') {
        if(!headers_sent()) {
            header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
            header(sprintf(
                'Location: https://%s%s',
                $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
                $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
            ));
            exit();
        }
    }
    // comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
    ('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', false);
    defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'prod');

    require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
    require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

    $config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');

    (new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
    ```
11. From the Azure Portal / Web App / Application settinh, .change the default directory from site\wwwroot to site\wwwroot\web
12. Restart the Web App.

The home page them now loads successfully but with a 404 Error within the body and "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." when trying to access other pages in the header.

I also noted that I have 2 .htacss file 
1x in my \site\wwwroot  and 1x in my \site\wwwroot\web
Haved tried deleting them and configure a web.config file in (site\wwwroot\web) but still not working.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>  
    <rewrite>  
        <rules>  
          <rule name="Redirect rquests to default azure websites domain" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />  
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^yoursite\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://mysitename.azurewebsites.net/{R:0}" />  
          </rule>  
        </rules>  
    </rewrite>  
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

As Yii2 is not famous in Azure Web App, can't find a solution anywhere. Will appreciate if you can help along.

Comment: Does your domain point directly to the "web" folder?

Comment: I have not performed DNS Switch. I want to make sure that it is correctly running to the azure.websites.net URl first.
For your question. Yes !! In the 11 step. I have change the default directory of my web app to "web" folder.